# Memory issues in coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, memory-management

I have almost 4000 MOC as registereds Objects with the Main MOC. When I reset it. My memory became 500 MB. When ever I create any releation ship btw managed Objects memory increases. pls suggest me to overcome form the memory issue. Thx in advance

Comment: Please give more details of your model, the data in your entity instances, the code for creating the instances, the instruments trace of the memory creation, details of what object type is taking most memory...

Comment: When I fill data into MOC, from the server, the memory goes to 400 MB.  And after inserting all the DATA i "RESET" the MOC and make it nil. And create it again(MOC) . But it does not decrease the 400MB .

Comment: You didn't not show any code nor your model.  You also have not provided any Instrument traces.  It is impossible to answer this question without at least some of that information.